# How can I improve the performance of a Dataflow job using the Firestore Bulk Delete template?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

### Problem

I'm seeing very low throughput when attempting to run a dataflow job using the following template: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/firestore-bulk-delete.

When running against our production dataset (~2.2 billion entities to remove) the throughput ramps up to ~500 entities per second within 2 hours. After 24 hours, the number of workers has not scaled out, and throughput has remained at ~500 entities per second. At this pace the job will take ~51 days to complete.

When I try running the same job on a smaller amount of data (~90 million entities to remove) the job will automatically scale out to ~11 workers, and ramp up to a throughput of ~7500 entities per second.

How might I improve the performance of this dataflow job when purging a large amount of data from datastore?

### What I've tried (without success)

1. I've confirmed that the dataflow job and workers are running in the same region as datastore.
2. I've tried setting numWorkers to 20, but it quickly scales down to 1.

Comment: In theory, since you learned that a smaller job is more efficient, why not split into smaller chunks that work more efficiently?  Don't ask me how, but in theory, it sounds like it would work.  Perhaps  500 million at a time, or if it can handle 1 billion ok, that would be easier so you only have to do it 100 times.

Comment: @easilyfixed I appreciate the suggestion. This is certainly plan B.

Comment: Are you using an inequality query with that template?  If so, that would reduce the workers down to 1.